# While Loop Syntax Error in Wingware

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error

I'm using a while loop in some code. This is the third one in this given program, all of them are formatted the same, yet for some reason one specific line is giving me syntax error. I have tried copying and pasting it directly from another portion of my while loop, and nothing seems to be rectifying it. I'm absolutely baffled. Perhaps another set of eyes can see what I'm missing?

[image: Syntax error in question]

Comment: Please add the code and not an image of it.

Comment: As in 90% of the syntax error questions, it's because of a missing parenthesis on the previous line.

Comment: @Piinthesky Syntax errors don't have tracebacks, since they occur during parsing, not during execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close the parenthesis on the previous line

Comment: @thewaywewere How is this requesting clarification?

Comment: But you shouldn't waste time posting an answer to simple typo questions, just vote to close.